# Ubuntu logs out after changing fonts

Tags: 14.04, fonts, unity-tweak-tool

Ubuntu 14.04 `Linux 3.13.0-63-generic` logs out immediately after I change fonts in Unity Tweak Tool. I faced this problem today. Unity Tweak Tool worked just fine a few days back. And no, it does not log out while I change themes or icons.

Comment: What font in which area are you trying to change?

Comment: the default fonts.

Comment: I'm too facing similar issues on 3.13.0-34-generic